# convert rows to column using pivot SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have some data in following format :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpHnz.png

could some one plz tell me how to pivot it to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wulVc.png

I have multiple set of such rows for each BatchNo and TransactionDate and want one batchno to be pivoted to one row and so on....

**Update** from comment a tried SQL not working (cf. comments on details):

```
SELECT 
  [1] UnitId, [2] Time, [4] Date, [5] A, [6] a, [8] b, [9] c, [10] ABT, 
  [11] BatLevel, [12] SC, [13] GC, [14] OB, [17] CO, [18] VO, [19] PO, 
  [20] PU, [21] CCB 
 from ( 
    select * 
     from [ProductTCPTransaction] 
 ) src 
 PIVOT ( 
    COUNT(TransactionDate) 
    FOR ParameterID 
    in ([1],[2],[4],[5],[6],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12], 
        [13],[14],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21]) 
 ) piv
```

Comment: Please provide data and code in "text" form ... thanks.

Comment: cannot paste data as it doesn't appear in tabular form

Comment: Hm, whatever tabular form means for a minimal sample ... but the SQL you tried (best effort) or where you got stuck, should be OK to type in, right? Someone offering a solution, is expected to type in data, to check before handing it out? Interesting idea ;-)

Comment: Oh sure the query I tried is : 




SELECT  
  [1] UnitId,
  [2] Time,
  [4] Date,
  [5] A,
  [6] a,
  [8] b,
  [9] c,
  [10] ABT,
  [11] BatLevel,
  [12] SC,
  [13] GC,
  [14] OB,
  [17] CO,
  [18] VO, 
  [19] PO, 
  [20] PU, 
  [21] CCB
from
(
   select *
   from [ProductTCPTransaction]
) src
PIVOT
(
 COUNT(TransactionDate)
 FOR ParameterID in 
  ([1],[2],[4],[5],[6],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],
  [13],[14],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21])
) piv

Comment: but it yields un-intended results which are of no use to me

Comment: ID ParameterID BatchNo ParameterValue ConnectionID TransactionDate
40367 1 502854367 +917506711342 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40368 2 502854367 172500 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40369 4 502854367 310316 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40370 5 502854367 A 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40371 6 502854367 0 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40372 8 502854367 1 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40373 9 502854367 1 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40374 10 502854367 038 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40375 11 502854367 108 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40376 12 502854367 010 5 2016-07-06 13:53:15.493
40377 13 502854367 010 5

Comment: Added query to the question (where it belongs ;-) ... please also add above unwanted result, it helps the professional pivoters to instantly help, I guess ...

Comment: UnitId Time Date  A a b c ABT BatLevel SC GC OB CO VO PO PU CCB
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

Comment: Please update the question accordingly (my edit only has a 50% chance to go through ...) optimal would it be done completely by the OP ;-)

Answer (score 2):

So how about this, you can add the rest yourself ;)

```
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Unpiv') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Unpiv

    CREATE TABLE #Unpiv
    (
        ParameterId int not null,
        ParameterValue varchar(30) not null,
        TransactionDate Date not null
    )

    INSERT INTO #Unpiv
    SELECT 1, '+917506711342', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 2, '172500', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 4, '310316', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 5, 'A', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 6, '0', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 8, '1', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 9, '1', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 10, '038', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 11, '108', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 12, '010', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 13, '010', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 14, '005', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 17, '000', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 18, '238', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 19, '000', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 20, '00000', '07/06/16'
    UNION
    SELECT 21, '00034', '07/06/16'

    SELECT
        [1], [2], [4], [5], [6], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], TransactionDate
    FROM
        #Unpiv
    PIVOT (MAX(ParameterValue) FOR ParameterId IN ([1], [2], [4], [5], [6], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13])) P
```